# higher order gradient through py_function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wonder how to calculate higher order gradients through tf.py_function in tf2.0.  The following example (slightly modified from tensorflow doc) produces the correct dy_dx, and aa_x is None.  Thank you.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

def huber(x, delta):
  if tf.abs(x) <= delta:
    return x*x/ (2*delta)
  else:
    return tf.abs(x)-delta/2.0



x = tf.constant ([2.0 ] )         
z = tf.constant ([1.0 ] )

with tf.GradientTape (persistent=True) as g0:
  g0.watch(x)

  with tf.GradientTape (persistent=True) as g :
    g.watch (x)
    y = tf.py_function(func=huber, inp=[x, 3.] , Tout=tf.float32  )

  dy_dx = g.gradient(y, x)
  aa = tf.reduce_sum(dy_dx *z )

aa_x = g0.gradient (aa, x)
print (dy_dx)
print (aa_x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the **documentation** of `tf.py_function` you cannot compute the higher `>1st` derivative. This function allows expressing computations in a **TensorFlow graph** as **Python functions**. In particular, it wraps a Python function `func` in a **once-differentiable** TensorFlow operation that executes it with eager execution enabled.  Meaning you can only differentiate it **once**.

If you want to get **higher-order derivatives**, you can just use  **gradient** function normally in **Tensorflow 2.1.0**.

**Modified Code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf     # Tensorflow 2.1.0
import os


def huber(x, delta):
  if tf.abs(x) <= delta:
    return x*x/ (2*delta)  ## x^2  / 2*delta  
                           ## x / delta   - 1st derivative
                           ## 1 / delta   - 2nd derivative
  else:
    return tf.abs(x)-delta/2.0 


x = tf.constant ([2.0 ])         
z = tf.constant ([1.0 ])

with tf.GradientTape (persistent=True) as g0:
  g0.watch(x)

  with tf.GradientTape (persistent=True) as g :
    g.watch (x)
    # y = tf.py_function(func=huber, inp=[x, 3.0] , Tout=tf.float32  )  # once-differentiable
    y= huber(x, 3.0)
  dy_dx = g.gradient(y, x)
  aa = tf.reduce_sum(dy_dx *z)

aa_x = g0.gradient(aa, x)

print (dy_dx)  #  tf.Tensor([0.6666667], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
print (aa_x)   #  tf.Tensor([0.33333334], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

You can read more about `tf.py_wrap` function in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function).